# Multiple sql servers default instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I tried to upgrade my mssql server from 2012 to 2014 but I ended up have two servers on my machine.

Now, whenever I connect to localhost it is always resolving to 2012 instance. 
SQL Configuration manager 2014 also shows 2012 instance.

How can I change the default instance point to 2014 instead? and Are there any issues uninstalling 2012 version.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing from you question that you didn't do an "in-place" upgrade.

You can only have 1 SQL Server as the default instance, I believe the SQL Server installer will detect this automatically, and create a new instance for any subsequent installs.

If you absolutely have to have SQL Server 2014 as your default instance, you will need to uninstall SQL Server 2012 and re-install SQL Server 2014, or do an in-place upgrade of your SQL Server 2012.

Comment: How can I connect to 2014 instance?